# Linq query for using LIKE operator doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have created a SQL Server stored procedure which I have bound to my class property like below.

```
objSearchCustomerCDTO = DbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchCustomerCDTO>("exec GetSearchCustomerDetails").AsQueryable().ToList();
```

Please note that I have simply used the stored procedure to bind to my properties

For example : my class have below property

```
public string CustomerName {get;set;}
```

and stored procedure returns

```
Select c.CustomerName as CustomerName from Customer
```

Now I want to display only the `CustomerName` containing `bil` - for that I have used this query, but I don't know why it is always null

```
var query = objSearchCustomerCDTO
            .Where(c => c.CustomerName.Contains("bil")).ToList();
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in the above query.

Thanks

Comment: *What* is always null? `ToList()` won't return null. It may return an empty list, but that's a different matter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
var query = objSearchCustomerCDTO
            .Where(c => c.CustomerName.ToLower().Contains("bil")).ToList();
```